# Parsing an object in stream function

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal

How can I parse String to BigDecimal in the stream function, I would like to keep property set as a String and then parse it to BigDecimal and finally getting the sum of totals by calculating totals taken from each object. (currently on the BigDecimal::add there is a message cannot resolve method add) Thank you.

```
public Optional<BigDecimal> generalTotalForSingleInvoice(PDDocument pdDocument) {
    return Optional.of(new BigDecimal(findFirst(extractText(pdDocument), INVOICE_GENERAL_TOTAL)
            .replaceAll("\\.", "")
            .replaceAll(",", ".")).stripTrailingZeros());
}

public Optional<BigDecimal> sumOfGeneralTotal(List<PDDocument> document) {
    return document.stream().map(this::generalTotalForSingleInvoice).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

}
```

Comment: @Eran thank you it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `Stream<Optional<BigDecimal>>`, and you can't reduce that `Stream` with a `BinaryOperator<BigDecimal>`, so `BigDecimal::add` doesn't fit.

Since your `generalTotalForSingleInvoice` can never return an empty `Optional`, it has no reason to return an `Optional`. You can change it to:

```
public BigDecimal generalTotalForSingleInvoice(PDDocument pdDocument) {
    return new BigDecimal(findFirst(extractText(pdDocument), INVOICE_GENERAL_TOTAL)
            .replaceAll("\\.", "")
            .replaceAll(",", ".")).stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

Now, your original `Stream` pipeline will work, but note that the `reduce` variant you are using doesn't return an `Optional` (since you are passing an identity value), so you should change the return type of the method:

```
public BigDecimal sumOfGeneralTotal(List<PDDocument> document) {
    return document.stream().map(this::generalTotalForSingleInvoice).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Excusing the return type based on the implementation of `generalTotalForSingleInvoice`, you can still use `filter` and `map` to ensure only `PDDocument` which *are present* contribute to accumulation in your reduction:

```
return document.stream()
        .map(this::generalTotalForSingleInvoice)
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .reduce(BigDecimal::add);
```